Determine link to node ratio in QGIS based on OSM raw route data. Want Nodes only at "end as cul-de-sac or at links intersection" not in between
I used dissolve n polyline tool to make continuous route link then used vertices tool to get nodes. Then used count tool to get only vertices at end or in-between using criteria numb count(degree) =1 or numb count > 2, but it led to obvious reduction in those routes where nodes are two. Further aggregate tool to get link count but not got desired output.
Tell me how to get two columns one for nodes count for all routes (within different wards or blocks) and respective links.
Note node means only at link intersection or at link end as Cul de sac.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
